# vscode get object properties to the top of the suggestions

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried several things in `settings.json`, I still can't get the properties to be ordered on `top`.

for example, take `ADD_CONTACT` object, I start typing `dele` and the properties priority seems to be on the bottom always.

[image]

As for pressing `Ctrl + Space` to show suggestions, taking the following for example the `contact` and `id` are not even listed:

[image]

Here's what I tried in `settings.json`:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "bottom",
"editor.suggest.localityBonus": true,
"editor.suggest.filterGraceful": true,
"editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions": true,
```

Also:

```
"editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

has anyone faced this issue before and has some kind of settings for this? any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try turn the Intellisense engine option to 'default'. 'tag parser' option brings fuzzy suggestions that are out of context, and  'disabled' just turns Intellisense off